# Time Complexity Python Script

Tags: python, big-o, time-complexity, python-itertools

I am writing a small script that guesses numeric passwords (including ones with leading zeros). The script works fine but I am having trouble understanding what the worst case time complexity would be for this algorithm. Any insight on the complexity of this implementation would be great, thanks.

```
def bruteforce(cipherText):
    for pLen in itertools.count():
        for password in itertools.product("0123456789", repeat=pLen):
            if hashlib.sha256("".join(password)).hexdigest() == cipherText:
                return "".join(password)
```

Comment: A few side notes: (1) There is no reason for both `break` and `done` here; just get rid of `done` and use `while True`. (2) Or, even better, use `for pLen in itertools.count():` instead of maintaining `pLen` manually. (3) Don't use parentheses around `if` tests or similar in Python. (4) Don't use parentheses around arguments to `not`; it's an operator, not a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it's always possible that you're going to find a hash collision before you find the right password. And, for a long-enough input string, this is *guaranteed*. So, really, the algorithm is constant time: it will complete in about `2^256` steps no matter what the input is.

But this isn't very helpful when you're asking about how it scales with more reasonable `N`, so let's assume we had some upper limit that was low enough where hash collisions weren't relevant.

Now, if the password is length N, the outer loop will run N times.*

<sub>* I'm assuming here that the password really *will* be purely numeric. Otherwise, of course, it'll fail to find the right answer at `N` and keep going until it finds a hash collision.</sub>

How long does the inner loop take? Well, the main thing it does is iterate each element in `product("0123456789", repeat=pLen)`. That just iterates the cartesian product of the 10-element list `pLen` times—in other words, there are `10^pLen` elements in the product.

Since `10**pLen` is greater than `sum(10**i for i in range(pLen))` (e.g., `100000 > 11111`), we can ignore all but the last time through the outer loop, so that `10**pLen` is the total number of inner loops.

The stuff that it does inside each inner loop is all linear on `pLen` (`join`ing a string, hashing a string) or constant (comparing two hashes), so there are (10^pLen)*pLen total steps.

So, the worst-case complexity is exponential: `O(10^N)`. Because that's the same as multiplying `N` by a constant and then doing `2^cN`, that's the same complexity class as `O(2^N)`.

If you want to combine the two together, you could call this `O(2^min(log2(10)*N, 256))`. Which, again, is constant-time (since the asymptote is still `2^256`), but shows how it's *practically* exponential if you only care about smaller `N`.